# Обособленные конструкции, присоединяемые наречиями

Tags: синтаксис

Какие синтаксические конструкции присоединяют наречия? Примеры предложений с такими конструкциями: "Сначала сам выучись, а затем уже учи других"; "Вошли в прихожую, затем в комнату".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что наречия, в том числе местоименные наречия, ничего не присоединяют, так как союзами не являются.

Такие наречия используются в БСП или в простом предложении с однородными членами, при этом они выступают в роли  обстоятельств (времени, причины), например: Сначала сам выучись, а затем уже учи других. Кругом были люди, поэтому прощались они сдержанно. Краска слезла, дождевые трубы изломались, оттого на дворе стояли лужи.

В то же время они могут входить в состав союзов, например: ЗАТЕМ ЧТОБЫ (подч. союз), ОТТОГО И (присоед. союз), А ПОТОМ (И ПОТОМ) (присоед. союз: "не хочу ехать, а потом и денег нет").

Comment: Наречия, вроде как?

Comment: Вроде да - местоименные наречия.

Comment: > Думаю, что наречия, в том числе местоименные наречия, ничего не присоединяют, так как союзами не являются.

Да, союзами они не являются, но запятая перед ними все-таки ставится. Она не предваряет новую синтаксическую конструкцию?

Comment: "Сначала сам выучись, а затем уже учи других" - сочинительный союз А в ССП имеет значение противопоставления, а наречия выражают семантическую часть сообщения (временное соотношение событий). Отметим, что в СПП с придаточным времени обе функции берут на себя подчинительные союзы."Вошли в прихожую, затем в комнату". Это однородные сказуемые с бессоюзной сочинительной связью, которые сами по себе выражают какую-то последовательность действий, а наречие дополнительно уточняет, что эта последовательность связана со временем.

Comment: Благодарю Вас.